# Move DIVs with a click of a mouse?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a jQuery plugin or something which would allow my users on my website to click on DIVs and drag them around, changing their position. All I could find are some plugins that make data move from one DIV to another.

It's something like a puzzle, I'd like them be able to move them around the page for no reason.

Comment: So everyone can move any DIV and everyone gets updates on it realtime? Maybe websockets...

Comment: No, I meant like a javascript effect. No one else would see it nor it would save or anything...

EDIT: And Messiah, please explain me the obvious reason, I'm just asking

Comment: You're in luck, such a jQuery plugin exists: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define your DIV positions as `absolute` and react to `ondrag()` by recalculating the position

Answer (score 1):

In the future you should follow these steps:

> 1) Google what you want to do (appropriate terms here would be:
>   *javascript drag drop*)
>
> 2) Look at official sources, e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (and it's derivates) is
>   a neat plugin which simplifies handling of functionality you want to
>   implement.
>
> 3) Search stackoverflow if you find no solution.
>
> 4) Post something if you find no solution.

Nonetheless [here's](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) a posible solution for your question if you want to do it yourself. 
[Here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-drag-and-drop-plugins.html) are a few jQuery plugins that could fit your needs.